# Does $\frac{\text{clockrate}(P_2)}{\text{clockrate}(P_1)}=1.37$ say that $P_2$ is $37\%$ faster than $P_1$, or the opposite?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

Sorry for the trivial question, but ...

> Does this ratio say $P_2$ is $37\%$ faster than $P_1$, or the opposite? $$\require{cancel}
> \frac{ClockRate(P_2)}{ClockRate(P_1)} =  \left(\frac{(1.2 \times 10^9) \cdot 1.25 }{\cancel{\text{CPUTime}}}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\cancel{\text{CPUTime}}} { 10^9 \times 1.1}\right)= 1.37$$

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. The image isn't visible. We would like to see the actual mathematics. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

Since: $$P_2 = 137\%  P_1$$  and we are talking about rates, this means that rate $P_2$ is faster!